# Is there a way to call a function by name on different return types without inheritance in C++14?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a "router" object that contains a collection of different objects *which are not in the same inheritance hierarchy* where most function calls just inspects parameters and calls a function with the same name on a different object depending on parameters.  Ideally I want to do something like this:

```
struct bigtype {};
struct smalltype {};
decltype(auto) a() { return bigtype{}; }
decltype(auto) b() { return smalltype{}; }

template<typename ReturnType>
ReturnType& route(const params& params) {    
   if(params.test) {
       return a();  
   }
   return b();
}

//Many, many functions of this form
void pass(const params& params) {
   route(params).consume();
}
```

This will not compile since `a()` and `b()` have different return types.  In C++14, is there any way to write a function such as `pass` without putting `bigtype` and `smalltype` in the same inheritance hierarchy?  So far the best I can do is transforming the function to take a lambda containing the call, however this gets visually ugly for functions which take a lot of parameters.

```
template<typename FuncType>
decltype(auto) route(const params& params, FuncType&& funcType) {
  if(params.test) {
    return funcType(a());
  }
  return funcType(b());
}

void pass(const params& params) {
   //Very ugly for lots of parameters.  Much harder to visually parse quickly.
   route(params, [](auto&& router) { router.consume(); }); 
}
```

Even though I likely cannot use it, I would be curious to know the best C++17/C++20 solutions to this problem as well.

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is C++17, but some libraries, as boost, provide their version (compatible with C++14).

Comment: You can return a proxy object. The proxy object's `consume()` method checks the params and forwards to either `a` or `b`. This does require adding every method common to `a` and `b` to the proxy.

Comment: "which are not in the same inheritance hierarchy" Perhaps that's the problem. They implement the same interface, and you make a selection between them at run time. Looks like a classical inheritance application to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of the proxy object idea Raymond Chen mentions in comments. In the toy code below I just construct one or the other, `bigtype` and a `smalltype`, as a temporary and call its consume.

```
#include <iostream>

struct params {
    int val;

    bool test() const {
        return val > 5;
    }
};

struct bigtype {
    void consume() { std::cout << "a\n"; }
};

struct smalltype {
    void consume() { std::cout << "b\n"; }
};

class proxy {
    bool is_a;

public:
    proxy(const params& p) : is_a(p.test())
    {}

    void consume() {
        if (is_a) {
            bigtype().consume();
        } else {
            smalltype().consume();
        }
    }
};

proxy route(const params& params) {
    return proxy(params);
}

void pass(const params& params) {
    route(params).consume();
}

int main()
{
    pass({ 1 });
    pass({ 7 });

    return 0;
}
```

Depending on the details of your actual use case the proxy class may have to own a `bigtype` and a `smalltype` and forward to one of them in consume, however. You could have pointers to both and only dynamically allocate one of them.

Comment: This will work, but I feel like this is one level of abstraction too many.  Since the code in proxy::consume is basically a copy&paste from what I would write in my "pass" function without a proxy.  So it's not really buying anything.  Which is not surprising because in many ways my "router" conceptually *is* a proxy already.